# CentOS mail bounced error dsn=5.1.0 status postfix issue

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, postfix, email-server

I'm running centOs on my server and i use postfix for sending emails but a while ago postfix has started bouncing every mail i try to send giving this error:

```
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/pickup[20293]: 29475A24DC: uid=48 from=<apache>
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/cleanup[21656]: 29475A24DC: message-id=<0cbd7cf637a8c2f8dccee3364787fd92@www.nuovapalestraparadiso.it>
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/qmgr[20294]: 29475A24DC: from=<apache@IrideLamp1.localhost>, size=765, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/smtp[21658]: 29475A24DC: to=<info@irideprogetti.it>, relay=mx.irideprogetti.it[62.149.128.160]:25, delay=0.23, delays=0.05/0.01/0.06/0.11, dsn=5.1.0, status=bounced (host mx.irideprogetti.it[62.149.128.160] said: 550 5.1.0 4a6w1t00p1oDpDh01a6wKF dominio non valido / invalid domain (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/cleanup[21656]: 63DAAA24DF: message-id=<20160609100649.63DAAA24DF@IrideLamp1.localhost>
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/qmgr[20294]: 63DAAA24DF: from=<>, size=2845, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/bounce[21660]: 29475A24DC: sender non-delivery notification: 63DAAA24DF
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/qmgr[20294]: 29475A24DC: removed
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/local[21661]: 63DAAA24DF: to=<root@IrideLamp1.localhost>, orig_to=<apache@IrideLamp1.localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jun  9 12:06:49 IrideLamp1 postfix/qmgr[20294]: 63DAAA24DF: removed
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

I suspect it's a dns/mx records problem as the maillog says but i don't know how to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance

Update: This is my main.cf postfix file:

```
soft_bounce = no

command_directory = /usr/sbin

daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

#default_privs = nobody

#myhostname = host.domain.tld
#myhostname = virtual.domain.tld

#mydomain = 

#myorigin = $myhostname
#myorigin = $mydomain

#inet_interfaces = $myhostname
#inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
#inet_interfaces = localhost

inet_protocols = all

#proxy_interfaces =
#proxy_interfaces = 1.2.3.4

#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
#   mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

#mynetworks_style = class
#mynetworks_style = subnet
mynetworks_style = host

#mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
#mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
#mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/network_table

#relay_domains = $mydestination

#relayhost = $mydomain
#relayhost = [gateway.my.domain]
#relayhost = [mailserver.isp.tld]
#relayhost = uucphost
#relayhost = [an.ip.add.ress]

#relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients

#in_flow_delay = 1s

#alias_maps = dbm:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
#alias_maps = netinfo:/aliases

#alias_database = dbm:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = dbm:/etc/mail/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/opt/majordomo/aliases

recipient_delimiter = +

#home_mailbox = Mailbox
#home_mailbox = Maildir/

#mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
#mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail

#mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail
#mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"

#mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp

local_destination_recipient_limit = 300
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5

#mailbox_transport = cyrus

#fallback_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
#fallback_transport =

#luser_relay = $user@other.host
#luser_relay = $local@other.host
#luser_relay = admin+$local

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

#fast_flush_domains = $relay_domains

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
#smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name ($mail_version)

#local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
#default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20

debug_peer_level = 2

#debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
#debug_peer_list = some.domain

debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix


newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

setgid_group = postdrop

html_directory = no

manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES

smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_local_domain =
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_helo_required = yes

smtp_transport = relay
```

Comment: Your server doesn't know it's supposed to be accepting mail for `irideprogetti.it` but DNS says it is, is `irideprogetti.it` a virtual domain, or the only domain you run? BTW, ciao.

Comment: Ciao! Yes, it's a virtual domain.

Comment: If you can post your main.cf we can probably help a lot more quickly (feel free to obscure anything security wise).

Comment: sorry for replying so late, i updated my answer inserting main.cf file

Comment: No problems... is the myhostname value commented out for a reason?

Comment: What you should probably do is have look at this: http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html  and decide which scenario is you, I believe you're doing `separate domains, UNIX system accounts`

Comment: No reason, but i assumed that way "mydomain" would have get the default value(?)

Comment: To start you're going to need a `virtual_alias_domains` stanza, the `myhostname` value can be set by postfix, but it does rely on a proper DNS setup, and is better set normally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40944/discussion-between-nickw-and-tommaso-sebastianelli).